# where is SelectorEvent defined and how to import it for type-checking purposes?

Tags: typescript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I am using the below, standard (I assume) code to create a select interaction, add it on a map and take some actions when a feature is selected or deselected:

```
const select: Select = new Select({
  hitTolerance: 5,
  multi: false,
  condition: singleClick
});
this.map.addInteraction(select);


select.on('select', (se: SelectEvent) => {
  console.log('select fired: ', se);
  // do some stuff using se...
});
```

My problem is that I am using TypeScript and would like to take full advantage of type-checking but I can't figure out where to import `SelectEvent` from. So the above code fails type-checking with:

```
`TS2304: Cannot find name 'SelectEvent'`
```

When I try:

```
import {SelectEvent} from 'ol/interaction';
```

I get:

```
TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/ol/interaction"' has no exported member 'SelectEvent'.
```

The open layers - relevant section of my `package.json` is:

```
$ npm ls --depth=0 | grep -i ol | grep -v polyfill
├── @siedlerchr/types-ol-ext@1.0.0 (git+https://github.com/Siedlerchr/types-ol-ext.git#ec995982b2ba7aa4d415e67a350ec4b9f841ea37)
├── @types/ol@6.4.2
├── ol@6.4.3
├── ol-ext@3.1.15
```

Grepping for the `SelectEvent` type I found:

```
node_modules/@types/ol/interaction/Select.d.ts:declare class SelectEvent extends BaseEvent {
```

.. but it is not clear to me how to import this declaration (also it doesn't seem to even be exported to begin with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your grepping pointed out :

```
node_modules/@types/ol/interaction/Select.d.ts:declare class SelectEvent extends BaseEvent
```

It is exported in `node_modules/@types/ol/interaction/Select.d.ts` :

```js
    export class SelectEvent extends Event {
        constructor(type: SelectEventType, selected: Feature[],deselected: Feature[], mapBrowserEvent: MapBrowserEvent);
        deselected: Feature[];
        mapBrowserEvent: MapBrowserEvent;
        selected: Feature[];
    }
```

So you just need to import it directly from there, like so :

```
import { SelectEvent } from "ol/interaction/Select";
```

This should fix your issue.

By the way there is also an excellent support in another stack exchange [community](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to all kind of spatial software engineering questions.

Comment: This did work however I don't get how. My `node_modules/@types/ol/interaction/Select.d.ts` file has `declare class SelectEvent ..`, not `export class SelectEvent`.